# Grep in R matching getting non-digits

Tags: regex, r

I need to get the non-digit part of a character. I have problem with this regex in R (which according to regexpal should work):

```
grep("[\\D]+", "PC 17610", value = TRUE, perl = F)
```

It should return `"PC "` while it returns `character(0)`

Other test cases:

```
grep("[\\D]+", "STON/O2. 3101282    ", value = TRUE, perl = F)
# should return "STON/O2."
grep("[\\D]+", "S.C./A.4. 23567", value = TRUE, perl = F)
# should return "S.C./A.4."
grep("[\\D]+", "C.A. 31026", value = TRUE, perl = F)
# should return "C.A."
```

**Update**:

The job is to divide column `"Ticket"` (from the Titanic disaster database) into `"TicketNumber"` and `"TicketSeries"` columns. As for now, Ticket holds below e.g. values: `"A/5 21171", "PC 17599", "STON/O2. 3101282", "113803"`. So the ticket number column is for the first record `21171` and ticket series column `"A/5"`, and so on for next records.

For the record `"113803"`, TicketNumber should be `"113803"` and TicketSeries `NA`.

Help appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any solution using `grep` or you just don't care?

Comment: I care, but I don't have such yet..

Comment: Try `library(stringr);str_extract(x, '\\S+(?=\\s+)')#[1] "PC"        "STON/O2."  "S.C./A.4." "C.A."      NA` where `x <- c('PC 17610', 'STON/O2. 3101282    ', 'S.C./A.4. 23567', 'C.A. 31026', '31026')`

Comment: Thanks. `train$TicketSeries <- str_extract(train$Ticket, perl('\\S+(?=\\s+)'))` helped to add the mentioned column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sub` instead, utilizing the `\S` regex token to match any non-whitespace characters.

```
x <- c('PC 17610', 'STON/O2. 3101282    ', 'S.C./A.4. 23567', 'C.A. 31026')
sub('(\\S+).*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "PC"        "STON/O2."  "S.C./A.4." "C.A."
```

### EDIT

Otherwise, if you want to return NA for invalid or empty matches, I suppose you could do ...

```
x <- c('PC 17610', 'STON/O2. 3101282    ', 'S.C./A.4. 23567', 'C.A. 31026', '31026')
r <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('^\\S+(?=\\s+)', x, perl=T))
unlist({r[sapply(r, length)==0] <- NA; r})
# [1] "PC"        "STON/O2."  "S.C./A.4." "C.A."      NA
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how to return NA for sub('(\\S+).*', '\\1', "31026") ? PS: I updated the question to picture better my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, '\\S+(?=\\s+)')
#[1] "PC"        "STON/O2."  "S.C./A.4." "C.A."      NA
```

#### data

```
x <- c('PC 17610', 'STON/O2. 3101282    ', 'S.C./A.4. 23567', 
        'C.A. 31026', '31026')
```